# How to remove old repetitive python packages?

Tags: package-management, python, pip

I have the same exact packages installed in /usr/loca/lib/python3.7  and again in /python3.8 and again in /python3.10 .  I noticed from the properties of 3.7 and 3.8 that I have not even accessed them since 2019.

If I ran:  pip uninstall <package_name >
Then that would remove the latest ones of python3.10

So how can I remove the old ones?  Can I just rm those folders?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which version of Python you wish to use, and then have it call its own version of `pip`.

For example, `python3.7 -m pip uninstall <package_name>` will use the `pip` from Python 3.7 to uninstall the package for Python 3.7.

Comment: @Johny how can you use those versions of python then? Where are they installed? can you call the python binary with a full path name?

Comment: I can only run : python3.10 -m pip uninstall . .  or python -m pip uninstall .    Both would remove the latest ones.  If that means I dont have python3.7 3.8 installed, then why do I still have their packages installed?

Comment: @Johny look in `/usr/bin` and see if you have other python versions there. Also which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: only python3.10 exists in /usr/bin .  that's why I want to remove older version packages